# AutoIT click Flash button?

Tags: flash, automation, autoit

Is it possible to click a flash button using AutoIT? If so, can anyone please give me sample code for it?

Answer (score 2):

You can just do a screen click at a location if you know where the button is going to be and that it is there.

If you don't know the state of the flash button (if it is there or not, where it is exactly) you could have a script that takes a screenshot, processes the image, and then creates and runs an AutoIT script that clicks the button.  I've had to do this in the past with Perl and ImageMagick.

Comment: Hi Thank you Narthring can you please show me any sample code for AutoIT click on flash or iteracting on flash .. i google searched it but i cant understand them can you refer any link or any code .. Thanks again

Comment: Just use the MouseClick function to click on the appropriate area:  http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm  You'll need to know where to click ahead of time and pass those X and Y coordinates into the function.

Answer (score 0):

Without taking a screenshot, you can calculate a hash of a pixel with `PixelChecksum`. Then you compare with a previous version you calculate. You will need to check a range of pixel areas.

https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/PixelChecksum.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using AutoIt to automate a flash game.

```
#include <IE.au3>

example()

Func example()
    $oIE = _IECreate("http://andkon.com/arcade/puzzle/greatmatemaster/")

    Local $oEmbedFlash = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "embed", 0)
    Local $hWin = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, "hwnd")
    WinSetState($hWin, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)

    ;get the x/y position of the flash game
    Local $iX = _IEPropertyGet($oEmbedFlash, "screenx")
    Local $iY = _IEPropertyGet($oEmbedFlash, "screeny")

    ;add click positions
    Local $aPlayChestBtn = [$iX + 240, $iY + 350]
    Local $a2b = [$iX + 120, $iY + 390]
    Local $a4b = [$iX + 120, $iY + 300]

    ;click the play chest button
    Click($aPlayChestBtn, 2000)

    ;move pawn to 4b with clicks
    Click($a2b, 1000)
    Click($a4b, 1000)

EndFunc   ;==>example

Func Click($aPos, $iWaitTime = 0)
    ;waits for a set amount of time for nothing to change where you want to click
    If $iWaitTime <> 0 Then PixelChecksumWait($aPos, $iWaitTime)

    ;clicks the area you want to click
    MouseClick("left", $aPos[0], $aPos[1], 1, 0)
EndFunc   ;==>Click

Func PixelChecksumWait($aPos, $iWaitTime = 5000)
    Local $iCheckSum

    ;wait to make sure there is no change in the region
    While 1
        ;get checksum
        $iCheckSum = PixelChecksum($aPos[1] - 5, $aPos[0] - 5, 10, 10)

        ;sleep to make sure there is no change
        Sleep($iWaitTime)

        ;exit loop if there was no change
        If $iCheckSum = PixelChecksum($aPos[1] - 5, $aPos[0] - 5, 10, 10) Then ExitLoop
    WEnd
EndFunc   ;==>PixelChecksumWait
```